# 2 independent auto_incremental fields in MySQL table

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I am trying to create a MySQL table that has a generic ID column, but also a secondary ID column, both of which need some form of auto incrementing

currently my MySQL table looks like this:

```
   `ban_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `student_uuid` varchar(36) NOT NULL,
   `student_ban_id` tinyint unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   (a bunch of data irrelevant to this question)
   PRIMARY KEY (`student_uuid`, `student_ban_id`),
   UNIQUE (`ban_id`)
```

The desired behavior is that ban_id is just a generic entry_id and that student_ban_id is the ban's number for the given student. (my reasoning is that I want to be able to reference bans by an id value if the student_uuid is unavailable, but the program spec also requires the ability to take student:banID as a valid means of reference)

A example row might be BanID:501, {studentUUID}, studentBanID:2 (501st ban, 2nd ban against the given student)

I have run into the issue that the MyISAM engine does not support tracking two separate incremental columns at once (I believe it can handle both desired behaviors, but not at the same time)

What might be the best way to achieve such a behavior?

Much appreciated!
-Cryptic

Comment: Does it have to be "2", or can it be any `student:banID` as long as it is unique (for the student)? Then you can just use banID and copy it to `student:banID` (or just directly use that column), you will still have "the ability to take student:banID as a valid means of reference". And you can always calculate how many bans there are currently if you need to display it somewhere. If it has to be consecutive, you need a counter (you can e.g. add that column to the `student`-table).

Comment: it needs to be consecutive for that student. if it's his 3rd ban it will be 3, 4th ban: 4, etc. and this will be one of the primary means to reference a row on the table

Comment: Then why again do you need the BanID? From your question I assume you are using MyISAM - MyISAM can do your BanID per student. You don't need 2 "primary keys".

Comment: truthfully, I probably don't. But It would be nice to be able to reference the table reliably without need for the student_uuid. (primarily for user-interface purposes)